# Qt Quick 2.0 UI Application Not Displaying on Touch Device

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

I'm trying to run a tiny (very tiny) Qt Quick 2.0 UI application on my Ubuntu Touch device (Galaxy Nexus Phone). Qt Creator successfully pushes to the device (copies via ADB and runs QMLScene) but I'm not seeing the application on the device.... that is until I open another application and then close it. During the app closing animation I am able to see my application (for a brief second) until the Ubuntu Touch main chooser application comes up. Is there a special way to switch to my application? Normal swipe from the right doesn't put my application into view. My device is running the March 28th build.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a .desktop file for your app, and does it match the app's name?  You should see, when launching it on the device from QtCreator, a line that looks like this in the Application Output pane:

```
qmlscene <app>.qml --desktop_file_hint=/home/phablet/<app>/<app>.desktop
```

If you don't have a .desktop file that matches what's being passed to --desktop_file_hint, then the Touch shell won't know enough about the window your app is creating to manage it properly.